# QRubberBand.geometry().intersects(???) How to find intersecting images in QGraphicsScene?

Tags: python, pyqt

I found few codes which demonstrates `intersects`, but it was mainly buttons. Something like this:

```
for child in self.findChildren(QPushButton):
    if rect.intersects(child.geometry( )):
        selected.append(child)
```

But how do you find images intersecting in your GraphicsScene with "Marquee" selection(QRubberBand)? I tried replacing findChildren(QPushButton) with QPixmap, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsPixmapItem it always giving me back empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the QRubberBand that has the QGraphicsView you have to use the rubberBandChanged signal and next to the items method you get the items that are below the QRubberBand.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import random


def create_pixmap():
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(100, 100)
    pixmap.fill(QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3)))
    return pixmap


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
        self.rubberBandChanged.connect(self.on_rubberBandChanged)

        for _ in range(5):
            item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(create_pixmap())
            item.setPos(*random.sample(range(500), 2))
            self.scene().addItem(item)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QRect", "QPointF", "QPointF")
    def on_rubberBandChanged(
        self, rubberBandRect, fromScenePoint, toScenePoint
    ):
        r = QtCore.QRectF(fromScenePoint, toScenePoint)
        selected = self.items(rubberBandRect)
        print(selected)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = GraphicsView()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you are using another QRubberBand the logic is similar to that since you must use the [items()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#items-3) method of QGraphicsView

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import random


def create_pixmap():
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(100, 100)
    pixmap.fill(QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3)))
    return pixmap


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self))
        self._rubberBand = QtWidgets.QRubberBand(
            QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self.viewport()
        )
        self._rubberBand.hide()
        self._origin = QtCore.QPoint()

        for _ in range(5):
            item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(create_pixmap())
            item.setPos(*random.sample(range(500), 2))
            self.scene().addItem(item)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self._origin = event.pos()
        self._rubberBand.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self._origin, QtCore.QSize()))
        self._rubberBand.show()
        super(GraphicsView, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self._rubberBand.setGeometry(
            QtCore.QRect(self._origin, event.pos()).normalized()
        )

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self._rubberBand.setGeometry(
            QtCore.QRect(self._origin, event.pos()).normalized()
        )
        selected = self.items(self._rubberBand.geometry())
        print(selected)
        self._rubberBand.hide()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = GraphicsView()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you. Just want to clarify one thing. QRubberBand  which is built in QGraphicsView keep updating every time coordinates change. Is it not going to slow down process , compare to second option which is going to check what you selected after you release button?

Comment: @Vlad Why do you think it will slow down? It would slow down if a heavy task would be executed while moving. What heavy task is being done? at least in my code no, just print the items that do not consume any time. So the answer you indicate is: it depends on the task you do.